# How to setup MySQL database tables for an Android Studio Application?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database-design

currently I am developing an app for my final class in college. The concept of the app is a Contact keeping app, essentially a user will be greeted by a login screen where they can either login if they already have an account or register if they don't. When you register the user will be prompt to enter their name, username, password and email. They then submit it and they will again be greeted by the login screen where they can now login in with their recently created credentials. Once they login successfully they be be show an Activity that welcomes them with their name that is retrieved from the table in the database by matching the username and password on the login, it retrieves all the information in that row. I pretty much have that down but what I am having trouble with is where am I going to hold the contacts that the users wants to save, I know that is has to be in another table but how am I going to set it up so I can match the a certain user to all of their contacts in the other table.

Once I get that information I need to put it on a ListView so the user can see their contacts and scroll through them, they can then add, delete or edit them.

As of right now I am able to register, login and display the welcome screen with no problem now I just need to be able to add, delete and edit contacts.

Java is used for the Android Studio part and PHP is used for the file that make the connection in the host online.

I am using Volley and JSON request.

The database and PHP files that make the request to the database are hosted in 000webhost.

Comment: You can start from here [Android CRUD Tutorial](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/02/android-sqlite-tutorial.html)

Comment: Sounds like a tough one.  Good luck! 

Can you provide us with a little bit more than just the assignment?  What have you tried already? Can we see your code so that others can tinker around with it?

Comment: I need help on how to setup the tables on the database. Table 1 Users: id, name, username, password, email fields. Then I have Table 2 Contacts: id, user_id, firstname, lastname, phone, email. I want to know how to match those 2 tables up I'm think with the user_id but i don't know if I'm in the right track

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a simple CRUD application.
If you use a RESTful communication model it's quite simple to achieve.
As for storing the contacts, you can have a file specific to each user and have that file's URI on the user's table in the DB. The file can be CSV, or JSON which is easily convertable into POJOs with the right API.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

First, create a MySQLite Helper class

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";
public static final String COLUMN_CONTACTS_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_USERNAME ="username";
public static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password"

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Contacts.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_CONTACTS_CREATE = "create table "+ TABLE_CONTACTS+
        "("+COLUMN_CONTACTS_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement, "
        +COLUMN_NAME+" text not null, "
        +COLUMN_USERNAME+" text not null,"
        +COLUMN_PASSWORD+" text not null);";


public MySQLiteHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database){
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CONTACTS_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),"Upgrading database from version "
            +oldVersion
            + " to"
            +newVersion
            +", which will destroy all old data");

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_CONTACTS);

    onCreate(db);
}}
```

Then a model class

```
public class ContactModel {
private long id;
private String name;
private String username;
private String password;
///////////
public long getId(){
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id){
    this.id = id;
}
//////////
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public void setUsername(String username){
    this.username = username;
}
////////////
public String getPassword(){
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password){
    this.password = password;
}    }
```

Then a datasource

```
public class ContactsDataSource {

private SQLiteDatabase database;
private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
private String[] allContactsColumns = {MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CONTACTS_ID,MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME,MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_USERNAME,
        MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PASSWORD};

public ContactsDataSource(Context context){
    dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close(){
    dbHelper.close();
}


public ContactModel createContact(String name, String username, String password){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME, name);
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_EMAIL,username);
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PHONE,password);
    long insertContactsId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS,allContactsColumns,MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CONTACTS_ID+" = "
            +insertContactsId, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    ContactModel newContact = cursorToContact(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    Log.d("written", "Info was written");
    return newContact;
}


public void deleteContact(ContactModel contact){
    long id = contact.getId();
    System.out.println("Comment deleted with id: "+id);
    database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS,MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CONTACTS_ID
            +" = "+id,null);
}


public ArrayList<ContactModel> getAllContacts(){
    ArrayList<ContactModel> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, allContactsColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        ContactModel contact = cursorToContact(cursor);
        contacts.add(contact);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return contacts;
}

private ContactModel cursorToContact(Cursor cursor){
    ContactModel contact = new ContactModel();
    contact.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
    contact.setUsername(cursor.getString(2));
    contact.setPassword(cursor.getString(3));
    return contact;
}}
```

You access the datasource as follows:

```
    //Open the database
    dataSource = new ContactsDataSource(this);
    dataSource.open();
    //use datasource functions like create and delete
    datasource.close();
```

You can display the info in a listview by calling ContactsDataSource.getAllContacts(), and displaying the results using a custom listAdapter. The idea is that you will use the Data Source's functions to grab the data you want, and feed it into the model class. From there you can extract what you need for the listview. Let me know if you need more help with that.

You also mentioned wanting to make multiple tables in the database, and that is as easy as using the above code but just adding another variable, such as TABLE_CONTACTS2 = "contacts2", and duplicating the functions for that table.